# Active Admin : two column layout for show functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a object with 4 attributes. I want to display them in a 2*2 table through Active Admin, by default Active Admin show page shows 1 attribute per row. Can anyone please tell me how to override this behaviour.

Note: I don't want to write a partial for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveAdmin is tough to customize.

You could do some workarounds, like reduce number of columns from 4 down to 2:

```
index do
  column :attr1, do |item|
    item.attr1
  end
  column :attr2 do |item|
    item.attr2
  end
end
```

And then insert custom stuff inside those two blocks.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveAdmin is easy to customize. Try this for instance:

```
show do
  columns do
    column do
      attributes_table do 
        row :attr1
        row :attr3
      end
    end
    column do
      attributes_table do 
        row :attr2
        row :attr4
      end
    end       
  end
end
```